# How to call every nth element in a list of Dates in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
My Date = 2015-07-30
          2015-07-31
          2015-08-03
          2015-08-04
          2015-08-05
          2015-08-06
          2015-08-07
          2015-08-10
          2015-08-11
          2015-08-12
          2015-08-13
          2015-08-14
```

How can I call every 2nd date from here?
I tried this but this doesn't work.

```
for i in range(0, len(Date), 2):
        abc = Date[i]
```

Comment: What is `MyDate`? A list? Furthermore what you you mean with "call"? What is the expected output?

Comment: Consider replacing your pseudo code with actual Python.

Comment: My Date is a list. The expected output is like 2015-07-31,2015-08-04,2015-08-06 etc every 2nd date.

Answer (score 6):

You can write this to get every other date (index 0, 2, 4, ...) from your list:

```
Date[::2]
```

To get the other dates (index 1, 3, ...), you can write:

```
Date[1::2]
```

You can look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/6419007) for an explanation of the slice notation.

Since `Date` is a list, you might want to call it `dates` in order to indicate it's a collection:

```
dates = """2015-07-30
2015-07-31
2015-08-03
2015-08-04
2015-08-05
2015-08-06
2015-08-07
2015-08-10
2015-08-11
2015-08-12
2015-08-13
2015-08-14""".split()
print(dates[::2])
# ['2015-07-30', '2015-08-03', '2015-08-05', '2015-08-07', '2015-08-11', '2015-08-13']
print(dates[1::2])
# ['2015-07-31', '2015-08-04', '2015-08-06', '2015-08-10', '2015-08-12', '2015-08-14']
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

```
my_dates = ['2015-07-30', '2015-07-31', '2015-08-03', '2015-08-04', '2015-08-05', '2015-08-06', '2015-08-07', '2015-08-10', '2015-08-11', '2015-08-12', '2015-08-13', '2015-08-14']
```

Using `list comprehension`:

```
print([my_dates[i] for i in range(1, len(my_dates), 2)])
```

Output:

```
['2015-07-31', '2015-08-04', '2015-08-06', '2015-08-10', '2015-08-12', '2015-08-14']
```

For above sample code, you can replace start index as `1` and observe by printing:

```
for i in range(1, len(my_dates), 2):
    abc = my_dates[i]
    print(abc)
```

Comment: @S.A Great! I think the other answer is more easier and efficient but I just tried to fix error in the sample code .`Happy Coding.`